# Spring JPA native query give a BigInteger and can´t cast to Double

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hello I try to do a Native Query to get a list of doubles, but I only get a Biginteger, and when I try to cast, send me a ClassCastException

**JpaRepository**

```
@Query(value="SELECT sum(case when t.estatus = 1 then t.totalm else 0 end) as sumProceso, sum(case when t.estatus = 2 then t.totalm else 0 end) as sumPagado,sum(case when t.estatus = 3 then t.totalm else 0 end) as sumCancelado FROM Solicitudes t WHERE t.CATALOGO_MEDICOS_ID = :SolicitudId", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Double[]> totalComisiones(@Param("SolicitudId") Long id);
```

**Service**

```
List<Double[]> tests = solicitudDao.totalComisiones(id);
    for (Double[] test : tests){

        Double doubleD = (Double)test[0];
        System.out.println(doubleD);

    }
```

**Console**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Double;
```

When I debug the response from the database is fine. Can you help me please.

Comment: You are selecting 3 different columns, I think you need an object with three double fields to be able to get these values, not `Double[]`, can you try to use a `List<TemObj>` where `TempObj` contains three double fields in it with getters & setters? Even that might not work, since selecting such generated values is OK when you have only single column response, not a multi-column, maybe you need to divide your select into three different select with each returning a single column?

Comment: Or you can maybe concat the result values into a single string value with 
`SELECT sum() || ',' || sum() || ',' || sum()`, then you'd get a `List<String>` then you can just split & get the array of values back?

Comment: The answer is in the question. The error message tells you that such a query returns an Object[], not a Double[]. And you found out yourself, according to the title, that the array contains instances of BigInteger, not Double. So change the return type to List<Object[]>, and cast the values to BigInteger, not Double. I wonder why you're using a native query instead of using a JPQL query, too.